# S3 resize on upload

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

I've been trying to run a lambda function when a file is uploaded to my S3 bucket. Every tutorial I follow uses an old version of their UI (basically everything is different) so it's really complicated to accomplish.

Right now, I have this:

[image: Basic config I have on my Lambda console]

The function I'm using is the only template containing he word "image". It uses the ImageMagick library that, as far as I could see, contains functions to resize an image.

I noticed the "handler" function is called by I don't know how to provide parameters to it. The function is being called but when checking for "req.operation" it is, of course, undefined. What am I missing here ?

Does anyone have an updated URL I could follow to accomplish this OR/AND the on the fly resizing using Lambda ?

Answer (score 2):

The *Introduction to AWS Lambda* self-paced lab at http://amazon.qwiklabs.com uses the new Lambda interface but the code is in Python.

The AWS [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) Tutorial has code for Node, Java and Python but creates the Lambda function via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

As an alternative to resizing images on upload, you could use a resizing service to provide images on-the-fly:

- [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)
- [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Their console changed a lot of times during the last months, so it's easy to get confused to what's going on if you follow an old tutorial. 
Try the functions templates for simple tests first to understand what happens. Every lambda when called, goes to a handler function with event and context parameters.

There is an example for resizing images on the fly with lambda, s3 and api gateway here: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-resizing, this is the function that handles resizing on lambda: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-resizing/blob/master/lambda/index.js

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problems with this [official blog post/tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) on the subject. (The "May 2018" update date at the top of that one is especially misleading, because I think the body of it hasn't been substantially revised in 18 months.)

But, happily, elsewhere in the AWS documentation I found this [Serverless Image Handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/welcome.html) guide.

It includes a CloudFormation template that basically sets up all the needed resources for you (Cloudfront URL, Lambda function, and API gateway). Once you point it at the S3 bucket where the source images live, you have a fully functional setup. That will suffice for production use in some cases (unless you have particular access restrictions you need to enforce).

A cool thing about this solution is that it uses the [Thumbor](http://thumbor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html) library, which has a couple dozen other image transformations it can do (e.g. color adjustment, rotation) in addition to scaling.